# Middleware does not work correctly in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have the following **middleware**.  I said when the URL is `"/contact"` or `"/admin"` or `"/about"` the middleware must run.
but when I go to `/` or `http://localhost:3000` the middleware fires.
It must fire when the URL is `"/contact"` or `"/admin"` or `"/about"`.

Why?

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'


export function middleware (request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(`Runs for '/contact' or '/admin' or 'about'`)
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/contact', '/admin','/about']
}
```

the structure of my pages folder

[image]

**`"next": "13.2.1"`**

**NOTE:**

**It works in development and does not work in production**

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `middleware.js` file is on the same level where the package.json in next-13. Before it was inside `pages` directory with `_middleware.js` name

you could try this to see if this works.

```js
export async function middleware(req, ev) {
  // showing the related code for your issue
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  if (pathname.includes("/contact") || pathname.includes("/admin")) {
    // for those routes add your logic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **/:path***

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/about/:path*', '/contact/:path*', '/admin/:path*'],
}
```

[Documentation for middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matching-paths)